# What is the limit on the length of an index or sequence's name?

Tags: postgresql

What is the limit on the length of an index or sequence's name?

I know it is 31 by default, but how can I see if it was changed?

What is the current one?

And what will happen if someone shrink the limit?

Will it crop the existing index names?

Is it different for different versions of PostgreSQL?

Comment: It's been 63 since forever (8, at least). It can only be changed by recompiling the server from source.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like comprehensive answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

It is 63 since forever (8, at least). It can only be changed by recompiling the server from source.

Thanks teppic for the comment.